# How to Launch a Universal Windows App from Angular with the URI from Browser and Pass Object to Automatically Login

Tags: angular, typescript, windows, encryption, uwp

How we should launch an UWP app from an angular code with URI from Browser and Pass some info to it as userid, password and other info. where we encrypt the credentials in angular app and decrypt in UMP app.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

> How we should launch an UWP app from an angular code with URI from Browser and Pass some info to it as userid

For this scenario, you could refer to [Handle URI activation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/handle-uri-activation) and register your app with uri scheme, when you launcher the specific url you could get the path and parameter from app's `OnActivated` method.

For example

```
<a href="testapp:login?userid=1234&password=7894">Launch</a>
```

App `OnActivated`

```
public static Dictionary<string, string> ParseQueryString(Uri url)
 {    
     if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(url.Query))
     {
         return new Dictionary<string, string>();
     }
    
     var dic = url.Query.Substring(1)
         
             .Split(new char[] { '&' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
           
             .Select(param => param.Split(new char[] { '=' }, 2, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
         
             .GroupBy(part => part[0], part => part.Length > 1 ? part[1] : string.Empty)
       
             .ToDictionary(group => group.Key, group => string.Join(",", group));

     return dic;
 }
 protected override void OnActivated(IActivatedEventArgs e)
 {
     // set up frame
     Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;

     if (rootFrame == null)
     {
         // Create a Frame to act as the navigation context and navigate to the first page
         rootFrame = new Frame();
         rootFrame.NavigationFailed += OnNavigationFailed;

         Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
     }

     Type deepLinkPageType = typeof(MainPage);
     if (e.Kind == ActivationKind.Protocol)
     {
         var protocolArgs = (ProtocolActivatedEventArgs)e;
         var dict = ParseQueryString(protocolArgs.Uri);
         switch (protocolArgs.Uri.AbsolutePath)
         {
             case "":
                 break;
             case "login":
                 //navigate to login page with above dict parameter
                 break;
          
         }
     }

     if (rootFrame.Content == null)
     {
         // Default navigation
         rootFrame.Navigate(deepLinkPageType, e);
     }
     // Ensure the current window is active
     Window.Current.Activate();
 }
```